# how to map postgres text type to @LOB in ejb3

Tags: hibernate, ejb-3.0, postgresql-9.1

How to map text type in postgres as @LOB and fetchtype.lazy in ejb3?

Comment: can't you specify the sqltype with annotations?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. EJB3 doesnot have any @Text annotation.